# Is it possible to write these pure_assert and const_assert macros?

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, constants

The GCC `__attribute__((pure))` and `__attribute__((const))` allow functions to be declared as non–side-effecting and referentially transparent, respectively; let's say I want to write `pure_assert` and `const_assert` macros, whose argument must be an expression of the appropriate level of strictness, that is:

```
assert(oops_a_side_effect());
```

Silently results in different behaviours in debug and release, but:

```
pure_assert(oops_a_side_effect());
const_assert(oops_read_a_global());
```

Would be a compile-time error, at least in debug builds. For what I should hope are obvious reasons, you can't just create a `pure_assert_impl` declared `__attribute__((pure))` and have the macro expand to it. So is it possible to write these macros?

Comment: I think the person who invented the term "referential transparency" should be punished in some way. I had to look it up, and Wikipedia states that when a function is referential transparent, then you can replace a call with its function result. Still not clear what the difference is from a function without side effects?

Comment: A true random number generator (i.e. hardware based) would have no side effects (calling it doesn't change the program state; all future calls remain truely random) but it's certainly not referentially transparent (can't replace function by its result, as it wouldn't be random anymore). "no side effects" is also known as a "pure function". As WP notes, any pure function or combination thereof is referentially transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does gcc enforce that *pure* and *const* functions cannot call non-pure or non-const functions, respectively?  If so, you could define a properly attributed function template which takes a function pointer as a template parameter, and let the macro expand to an invocation of that function template.  I assume you need to support functions that take parameters, this would work better with C++0x variadic templates or lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

gcc does not enforce purity or referential transparency in any way. These attributes are just hints for the optimiser. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there's a really *good* solution for this, but I've found a possibility for something like `const_assert()`, which *appears* to work with the two versions of gcc I have readily to hand (4.1.2 and 4.4.4).

```
#include <assert.h>

extern void dummy_void_function(void);

#define const_assert(x) \
  assert(__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_constant_p((x) == (x)), \
         (x), dummy_void_function()))

extern int function(void);
extern int __attribute__((pure)) pure_function(void);
extern int __attribute__((const)) const_function(void);
extern int global;
extern volatile int volatile_global;

void test(int arg)
{
  /* These cause compile-time errors: */
  const_assert(function() == 0);
  const_assert(pure_function() == 0);
  const_assert(volatile_global == 0);

  /* These don't: */
  const_assert(const_function() == 0);
  const_assert(arg == 0);
  const_assert(global == 0);
}
```

This is really checking whether the expression `(x) == (x)` is regarded as a compile-time constant by the compiler, and creating brokenness if it's not.  The "good" cases effectively become `assert(x);` and the bad ones generate compile-time errors:

```
$ gcc -c const_assert.c
const_assert.c: In function 'test':
const_assert.c:18: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
const_assert.c:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
const_assert.c:20: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

However, with optimisation enabled, it still produces errors in the expected cases, but one of them is a bit odd:

```
$ gcc -O -c const_assert.c
const_assert.c: In function 'test':
const_assert.c:18: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
const_assert.c:19: error: first argument to '__builtin_choose_expr' not a constant
const_assert.c:20: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

...you'd expect the result of `__builtin_constant_p()` to be regarded as a constant by definition!  So I'm not sure that I would really trust this for real code...

(And I don't have any good ideas right now for `pure_assert()`!)

Answer (score 0):

Tough luck, I'm afraid. Macros are expanded by the preprocessor, even before the compiler starts looking at the code.

What maybe *could* be a solution, is to let the assert test expression be evaluated regardless of release or debug mode, however let the result be tested only in debug mode.